# My text inputs are empty when I do a drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I did drag and drop with several divisions. Everything works correctly but when I do, my inputs are empty...

Do you know why I lose my data ([before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7od0L.png), [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtqXs.png))?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Code :

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".box")

let dragged

for (let div of divs)
{
    div.ondragstart = (e) =>
    { 
        dragged = div     
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", div.innerHTML)
    };

    div.ondragover  = (e) => e.preventDefault()

    div.ondrop = (e) =>
    {
        dragged.innerHTML = div.innerHTML            
        div.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain") 
    };
}

let divTable = document.createElement("div");
divTable.id = "DivTableGroupe" + numTableau;
divTable.className = "box" ;
divTable.draggable = "true";
```

Comment: Please replace all pictures of code with text-based [mcve]s

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the `div` variable in your drop handler.
It is different from the target `<div>` on which the drop is taking place.
To refer to the target `<div>` you can use `e.currentTarget` instead.

Also, there should be a `preventDefault()` in the drop handler.

```
div.ondragstart = (e) =>{ 
    dragged = e.currentTarget;
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", div.innerHTML)
};

div.ondrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dragged.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    e.currentTarget.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
};
```